# Are "def post" and "if.request.method == POST " the same?

Tags: python, django

Are `def post` and `if.request.method == POST` the same?

I've seen some using `def post(self, request)` and some using `if.request.method == 'POST'`. They both seem to work, at least for the tasks I've seen.

Is there difference?

Comment: can you show example of how def post is used?

Comment: Usually yes, since a class-based view performs some "routing" to these functions. But you can of course patch that routing, and thus let it work differently.

Comment: @BibekBhandari: I think they mean `post` in *class-based* views.

Comment: yes, class based view

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you mixed 2 main Django approaches: [function-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/) and [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/).
`if request.method == POST` - FBV,
`def post(self, request)` - CBV.
In FBV you usually write views as functions, where conditionally check what method was made. In CBV you are overriding some Django built-in classes and built-in methods in that classes.
And yes, this is the same action.
P.S. For beginners it is easier to start learning Function Based Views.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about class-based views. In that case, if you do *not* change the routing mechanism, the answer is **yes**.

Let us look at the [source code of the `View` class [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L30). Usually class-based views subclass from this class, and thus inherit the behavior of this class:

> ```
> class View:
>
>     # ...
>
>     http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch',
>                          'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
>
>     # ...
>
>     @classonlymethod
>     def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
>         # ...
>         def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>             self = cls(**initkwargs)
>             if hasattr(self, 'get') and not hasattr(self, 'head'):
>                 self.head = self.get
>             self.request = request
>             self.args = args
>             self.kwargs = kwargs
>             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>         # ...
>         return view
>
>     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         # ...
>         if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
>             handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), 
>                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
>         else:
>             handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
>         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
>
>     # ...
> ```

I here stripped away parts that are more or less irrelevant, and fixed the formatting a bit to make it more convenient to read.

As you can see, if you call the `as_view()` function (when you declare a `url(..)` or `path(..)`, then it basically constructs a function `def view(..)` that, and a reference to that function is linked with this URL.

Now the `view(..)` function, performs some operations (for example if the `head (...)` function is not implemented, it will later fallback on the `get (..)` function. The most important part is however that it calls the `self.dispatch(..)` function.

This dispatch function looks to the `request.method`. It converts this method to a lowercase variant, and then checks if that method is declared in the view. If it is, it will call the corresponding method (so in case `request.method == 'POST'`, it will call `post (...)` with `request`, `*args`, and `**kwargs`), and if the method is missing, it will basically return a "HTTP method not allowed response".

Note however that you can subclass the `as_view`, and `dispatch(..)` function, and thus change this behavior.

Furthermore strictly speaking, you can write your own `View` class, that of course can have totally different behavior, but I assume that this is not really the scope of this question.

The *class-based view* thus basically performs something like (this is not how the code looks like, but semantically it is approximately the same as):

```
def some_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        return self.put(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if request.method == 'PATCH':
        return self.patch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if request.method == 'HEAD':
        return self.head(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        return self.options(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if request.method == 'TRACE':
        return self.trace(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return self.http_method_not_allowed(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

given of course all these functions exists (that is *not* always the case). Furthermore the `options(..)` function is generated automatically: it inspects what functions *are* defined, and returns a list of the corresponding methods.